# Azure Web Sites - share login state across subdomains

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, azure-web-app-service

I have two websites on Azure Web Sites, and I'm using a CNAME to use them with my own domain name.

Let's call the two sites site1.example.com and site2.example.com.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and SimpleMembership. I want the user to be able to log in on site1.example.com, and for that logged-in state to be accepted by site2.example.com.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Both site1 and site2 are pointing at the same membership database (connection string set the same for both in web.config, and InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute set to look at that connection string)
- I have set the cookie domain to .example.com (in web.config, system.web authentication section)
- I have manually set the machineKey in the config for system.web to the same thing for both sites

However, if I log in on site1, then I am not logged in on site2. I can see that the .ASPXAUTH cookie is correctly set on .example.com, so it is visible to both.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: you are most probably missing a common `session` store for both sites. Frankly, I don't see any difference in achieving your goal in an `in-house IIS` vs `Azure Websites`. First try to achieve your goal locally, then ask Azure specific things, if any. Have you achieved your goal with local IIS?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the sites in question? Are they *both* MVC 4, *both* targeting .NET 4, etc.?

Comment: @Levi, both .NET 4.5 and MVC 4.

Comment: @astaykov I don't need a common session store - I just need the authentication cookie to be read by site2 (in the same way as site1 would read it if I came back a month later).

Comment: @AlexWarren then inspect with Fiddler whether the cookie is being sent to both the "sites".

Comment: Anything else different about the sites?  Do they both have the same <httpRuntime targetFramework> setting in config?

Comment: Is this an issue in production, or an issue when you are testing locally (i.e. where the website is running under localhost)?  I have found that if the cookie domain doesn't match the first level (e.g. example.com) of where the site is located.  Additionally, if running under localhost you need to set the cookie domain to blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX requests to login (like via Web API), try to include

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

something like

```
$.ajax({ method: 'POST',
        url: 'yourloginurl.com/api/login',
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, 
        success: function (data) { ... } });
```

After set the domain on httpCookie.

I spend a day to found this solution and this solve my problem.